# Good looking LaTeX code

Tags: code, scripts

I'm looking for some script (program) which would help in editing LaTeX code. Usually I have a mess in my .tex code, so it would be good if the script could align tabulars and so on. It would also be nice, if it allows editing code (for example replace every `$$` with `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` and vice versa).

Is there any program which is doing such a thing? It can be program, or a plugin of texstudio or a bash (python) script as well. However I don` want to change my editor (if it is of course possible).

Comment: note exactly, I`m not looking for editor but for program which just do things I wrote above.

Comment: You should tell us what platform you're working on. Solutions that work with *nix-based platforms may not work on Windows, for example.

Comment: @AdamGlos: Some of the listed editors have regular expression search-and-replace.

Comment: @Werner I would be hard-pressed to come up with a regex to align *tabulars*... It's not a well-formed question right now -- too broad -- but regex alone wouldn't help.

Comment: @SeanAllred: For that there's [`latexindent`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent?lang=en).

Comment: I`m working on Ubuntu/Kubuntu (14.04 for know).

Comment: Search/replace for `$$` might be harder than you think (in the general case), but a naive solution is an easy sed: `s/\$\$([^(\$\$)])\$\$/\\begin{equation*}\1\\end{equation*}/` *should* do it, I think (untested)

Comment: @SeanAllred You're missing an asterisk, I think. Else you'll only allow maths expressions which are very short. Maybe...

Comment: $$'s should be rather replaced by `\[` and `\]`, because the `equation` environment adds (roughly speaking) the numer of equation.

Comment: latexindent looks very good. For every other my problem it will probably be enough to define my own script (tabulars where the harders objects to handle). However I will wait if there is something better than that:)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke that's why I want to replace it. I`m used to use $$, but in my work I have to use equation instead.

Comment: Emacs (with AUCTeX): `C-c C-q C-e`.  (Won't do everything, but comes [close](https://xkcd.com/378/).)

Comment: True, it`s duplcation. Thank you for help:)